# merge 2 seperate arrays matching keys

Tags: php, arrays, object

I need to take the values in the fist array at the top and insert them into the bottom array and assign the `key` as `url` when they merge. How can I do this?

I tried `array_merge_recursive()`, but that didn't seem to do it.

**Before**

```
$batchedDomains = Array
(
    [0] => http://www.domain.com/1/
    [1] => http://www.domain.com/2/
)

$json_a = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pda] => 91.1624138732
            [upa] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pda] => 91.1624138732
            [upa] => 1
        )

)
```

**After**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pda] => 91.1624138732
            [upa] => 1
            [url] => http://www.domain.com/1/
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pda] => 91.1624138732
            [upa] => 1
            [url] => http://www.domain.com/2/
        )

)
```

Comment: Did you try something? there are several ways to accomplish such!

Comment: You should try and post your code with as much information as possible. There are several ways to accomplish this and it is quite simple.

Comment: The hardest part is that since the second object is an stdClass object you can't access its properties using brackets, but you need to use arrows and curly brackets, that's the hardest part, the rest is just a foreach loop. Also, the PHP source can be slightly more helpful there to work on

Comment: so sorry I have not had my morning coffee yet. This is for php and I have tried from `array_merge` `array_merge_recursive` as well as `array_push`

Comment: @CesarBielich Why do you have 2 times the same url in your expected output?

Comment: typo sorry, I edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through both arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and add the property `url` to the `stdClass object $v1` with the value `$v2`.

```
<?php

    $json_a = array_map(function($v1, $v2) {
        $v1->url = $v2;
        return $v1;
    }, $json_a, $batchedDomains);

    print_r($json_a);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pda] => 91.1624138732
            [upa] => 1
            [url] => http://www.domain.com/1/
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pda] => 91.1624138732
            [upa] => 1
            [url] => http://www.domain.com/2/
        )

)
```